# How I can add Quotes " " to Makefile variable using substitute method

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile variable as follows

```
L_PATH_INCLUDE = c:\dir1\include C:\dir2\include C:\dir3\include
```

I need to handover this to other tool which need this as

```
tool.exe add-include-dir "c:\dir1\include" "C:\dir2\include" "C:\dir3\include"
```

I tried following way but tool reporting error that there should not be variable with single character and I have used `$(space)`

```
$(subst $(space)," ",$(strip $(L_PATH_INCLUDE)))
```

Could it be possible in any other way without using $(space) or single character variable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no problem with placing quotes, it is not an interpreted symbol. But you need to place quotes around all the paths in L_PATH_INCLUDE and to achieve this I'd do that :

```
L_PATH_INCLUDE = c:\dir1\include C:\dir2\include C:\dir3\include

all:
    echo $(addprefix ",$(addsuffix ",$(L_PATH_INCLUDE)))
```

Which outputs this with `make all` :

> echo "c:\dir1\include" "C:\dir2\include" "C:\dir3\include"
>
> c:\dir1\include C:\dir2\include C:\dir3\include

You can just replace echo with your command and it'll do it.

Basically the idea is to use addprefix and addsuffix to add quotes at the beginning and at the end of each word in L_PATH_INCLUDE.

If you copy/paste my answer in your Makefile, please be aware of replacing the four spaces by a proper tabulation.

Answer (score 0):

```
L_PATH_INCLUDE = c:\dir1\include C:\dir2\include C:\dir3\include

L_PATH_INCLUDE_QUOTED := $(patsubst %,"%",$(L_PATH_INCLUDE))

$(info L_PATH_INCLUDE_QUOTED=$(L_PATH_INCLUDE_QUOTED))
```